# Main method in spring roo

Tags: jpa, spring-roo

I'm very new to spring roo and JPA. To start, I followed http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html to build a Pizza Shop website. Now I'd like to write some JPA queries to test the entities. Is it possible to write a main method to test?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo generate (or can generate) Testcases for the entities too. -- Do not let you misleading by the empty Test classes. They use the same AspectJ "injecting" technology for that Tests like for normal classes.

Of course you can "extend" that tests.